# lpstat is not showing all printers?

Tags: printing

I currently have about 6 printers installed on Ubuntu 13.10, but lpstat is only showing 3 of them.

What is the best way to debug this, so that I can print to all printers from the command line, just like I could from a GUI application?

Answer (score 1):

As a partial workaround, I used `lpstat -a`, although that lists more printers than I want.

Answer (score 0):

> lpstat  is  a  (partial)  simulation  for  the Solaris SystemV R4 print
>          facilities.  Please use lpq instead.

So, why don't use `lpq` instead? `lpq -a` should list all the available printers. After that you can use `lpq -P printer-name` to see details of an specific printer.

Comment: `lpq: lp: unknown printer`

Comment: @merlin2011 your environment variables `PRINTER`, `LPDEST`, `NPRINTER`, `NGPRINTER` are empty or non existen, try `lpq -a` to show all printers or specify a printer with the `-P` flag

Answer (score -1):

To debug more, open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and paste in this command:

```
sudo cat /etc/cups/printers.conf
```

`cat`, short for `concatenate`, shows files and print on the standard output.

Now you should see all printers listed, that are locally installed. If it shows only three, the remaining (and missing) are network printers discovered automatically.

Thats the first step.

The next is the log entries made by cups in `/var/log/cups/` folder.